# Find All Empty Cells in Column and Paste Formula in them

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm close to what i want to do but not sure if I'll have to change method completely to get this done.

The below code works almost completely. I want to find all empty cells in range: C2:C120 and enter a formula from another worksheet: Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("F57").

It finds empty cells but it copies the text in the F57 cell, which is #N/A at the moment, **not** the formula. The formula is =VLOOKUP(D57,'[Example.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$D$37,2)  but I can't enter it directly into the code as it will always look for D57, not dynamically.

Any help is hugely appreciated, hopefully it's a simple fix.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

   For Each rng In ws.Range("C2:C120")
   If IsEmpty(rng) Then
   rng.Formula = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("F57")

   End If

   Next

End Sub
```

Comment: For example, if Cells `C2` and `C3` were empty, what would be the exact desired formulas in those cells?

Comment: Hi VBasic, my current spreadsheet has data for 119 customer for 119 different properties with their own property codes(V/101 to V/119). Some of these properties are empty in my spreadsheet, I want to fill data of those empty properties from another spreadsheet(Example.xlsx) which has ALL properties filled with data. I use a VLOOKUP formula to match property codes for empty properties in my spreadsheet and find them in the Example.xlsx spreadsheet and pull data from it into my spreadsheet. Hope that makes sense. =VLOOKUP(D57,'[Example.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$D$37,2)

Comment: Am I correct that you want the formula to look in column D for the row that is being assessed in column C? (i.e if the loop is looking at `Range("C7")` and it's empty, we want the forumula to be `=VLOOKUP(D7,'[Example.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$D$37,2)`?

Comment: Once the formula copies over to my sheet it becomes: In my sheet my property codes are in Column A, same as in the example.xlsx. So look for property code located in "A7" from my sheet, and find it in: "Example.xlsx A2:D37" then paste the data from 1 cell to the right of it.(which contains customers name). If i copy paste formula myself it works perfect. =VLOOKUP(A7,'[Example.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$D$37,2)

Comment: Sorry to try to make it simple, look for data from my Column A in the other sheet in Column A, if they match: copy paste data from Column B from other sheet into my Column C. In other words: find property code of empty property in other sheet, then if found copy name from other sheet to my sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find an answer for this *specifically* though I'm sure i've come accross one before.

If I understand correctly, the following should work.

In your loop you can reference the `rng` row number in your formula.

You could use (note, not tested):

```
For Each rng In ws.Range("C2:C120")
    If IsEmpty(rng) Then
        rng.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(D" & rng.Row & ",'[Example.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$D$37,2)"
    End If
Next rng
```

This uses the [`Row`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.row) property of the `Range` object, which is the row number of whatever cell you are accessing in your loop in each iteration, and uses it as the row number for your **D57** part of your formula (per your posted formula).

Comment: Samuel you are the best, it does exactly what i wanted it to, and allows me to bring in the dates over in the correct format to be able to be used by another formula which was another headache I had. MUCH MUCH appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

### Update Data From Different Workbook

Adjust the constants in `updateCustomers`.

**The Code**

**Sheet1** (or wherever you have `CommandButton3`)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    updateCustomers
End Sub
```

**Module1**

```
Sub updateCustomers()
    ' Source
    Const wbsName As String = "Example.xlsx"
    Const srcName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const srcAddr As String = "A2:B37"
    
    ' Target
    Const tgtName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const LookupCol As String = "A"
    Const tgtAddr As String = "C2:C120"
    
    ' Ranges
    Dim src As Range
    Set src = Workbooks(wbsName).Worksheets(srcName).Range(srcAddr)
    Dim tgt As Range
    Set tgt = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(tgtName).Range(tgtAddr)

    ' The Loop
    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In tgt.Cells
        If IsEmpty(cel) Then
            On Error Resume Next
            cel.Value = WorksheetFunction _
              .VLookup(tgt.Parent.Cells(cel.Row, LookupCol).Value, src, 2, False)
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next

    MsgBox "Customers updated.", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub
```